# embed bing maps - pushpin

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I am trying to embed bing maps into web page and it works, but I want to show pushpin in embeded map on web page. As I can see it is not possible. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<div id="mapviewer"><iframe id="map" scrolling="no" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/?v=2&amp;cp=45.810280~15.957222&amp;lvl=4&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;cid=AF2FECA12C1AA81D!196&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;emid=8841ff8b-025d-e5a7-e37f-39b4d31b3b93"></iframe><div id="LME_maplinks" style="line-height:20px;"><a id="LME_largerMap" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=45.810280~15.957222&amp;lvl=4&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;cid=AF2FECA12C1AA81D!196&amp;form=LMLTEW" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">View Larger Map</a><a id="LME_directions" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=45.810280~15.957222&amp;lvl=4&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;cid=AF2FECA12C1AA81D!196&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;rtp=%7Epos.45.810279846_15.957221984000004_" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">Driving Directions</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pushpin in embedded maps with the 'pushpins' parameter, see the MSDN about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692180.aspx

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Embedded Map</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="font-family:Arial">
      <p>A simple embedded map.</p>
      <iframe width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
         src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/embeddedMap/v1/ajax/aerial?zoomLevel=10&center=47.5_-122.5&pushpins=47.5_-122.5"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of what are the options available:

***mapMode***
The style of the map. Valid values are: Road, Aerial, AerialWithLabels, Birdseye, BirdseyeWithLabels

***zoomLevel*** 
An int indicating a valid zoom level for the map style.

***center***
Two doubles separated by an underscore that are the latitude and longitude values of the coordinate of the center of the map.

***heading***
A double specifying the orientation of the map in degrees.

***pushpins***
Two doubles separated by an underscore that are the latitude and longitude values of the coordinate of the pushpin. Multiple pushpin locations are separated by a ~.

***culture***
A valid culture string. The default value is “en-us”.

Comment: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/8863/clipboard01lru.jpg So I can pass coordinates for pushpin but I cant pass data to show above pushin. See the screenshot on link.

Comment: Yes, that's it, you have the option described below.
Added to this, you can use an URL to the Bing Maps website: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx

Comment: How do we load the given iframe's src url over https?
We tried changing the protocol to https and adding the parameter s=1 ( https://dev.virtualearth.net/embeddedMap/v1/ajax/aerial?zoomLevel=10&center=47.5_-122.5&pushpins=47.5_-122.5&s=1) but the content is getting blocked.

Comment: The documentation does not include HTTPS support, therefore, it might be possible that it's not available.